# uploading the file to the path specified in .netcore

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, file-upload, asp.net-core-mvc

I save the uploaded file under root. How can I add this to the path I specified (@ "C: \ UploadsFolder")?

```
public JsonResult Test(FileModel model)
{
    string SavePath = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "wwwroot/img", model.FormFile.FileName);

    using (var stream = new FileStream(SavePath, FileMode.Create))
    {
        model.FormFile.CopyTo(stream);
    }

    return Json("");
}
```

in FileModel.cs

```
public class FileModel
{
    public string Files { get; set; }

    public IFormFile FormFile { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Be aware that this is a **dangerous** approach to file-uploads. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/file-uploads?view=aspnetcore-5.0#security-considerations for an explanation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work I think.so for that, the file will upload to C drive instead of wwroot.

```
string SavePath = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), (@"C:\", model.FormFile.FileName);
```